# HSQLDB: Error creating stored procedure if it already exists

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, hsqldb

I have an `addresses` table and would like to put the following query inside a stored procedure inside my HSQLDB database:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        addresses a
WHERE       a.address_id = ?
```

Here is my best attempt (after reading the [HSQLDB docs on procs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS sp_get_address_by_id()
    BEGIN ATOMIC
        SELECT      *
        FROM        addresses a
        WHERE       a.address_id = @address_id
    END
```

The intention, obviously, is to create the procedure unless it already exists. But when I run this I get:

```
Error: unexpected token: BEGIN required: ( : line: 2
SQLState:  42581
ErrorCode: -5581
```

What is going on here? What can I do to fix this? Is the rest of my procedure written correctly (particularly in how it accepts input and returns output)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you gave, you have one input parameter `address_id`. It should be of the same type as the address_id column of the table addresses. And output parameters as many as there are columns in the addresses table. You are required to specify the type of each of them and they should correspond to the types of the respectives columns.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_address_by_id(IN address_id INT, OUT address VARCHAR(100), OUT city VARCHAR(25), OUT country VARCHAR(25), OUT postaleCode VARCHAR(10)) 
   READS SQL DATA
   BEGIN ATOMIC
     SELECT a.address, a.city, a.country, a.postaleCode 
     INTO address, city, country, postaleCode 
     FROM addresses a 
     WHERE a.address_id = address_id;
   END
```

If you get stuck on a step, please let me know. I'll be very pleased to help.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: What if you dont want to use the OUT parameters and just want the result set like any other default stored procedures ?